# What kind of tefillin wrap on the wrist did Ashkenazi communities use in the past?

Tags: minhag, tefilin

Most Ashkenazim now use a method in the form of ש such as this one:

[image]

But were there any other methods? For example, one similar to the Sephardi way?

Comment: That is the oldest Ashkenazi minhag for wrapping the retzua around the hand. There are some variations found in the many Hasidic minhagim, but those obviously came much, much later.

Comment: I believe originally there were no customs of wrapping the tefillin to make different shapes or letters but then customs emerged all over the place.  From my understanding the original custom was to wrap once around the hand and then tie around the finger